# Kfold cross validation in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-fold

What im trying to do;
Get the K-fold cross validated scores of an SVM. The data has all numerical independent variables, and a categorical dependent variable. Im using python3, sklearn and feature engine.

My understanding on the matter;

The independent variable has NA values, all of them are below 5% of the total data points, so i imputed them using the median values from the train set, as the variables are not normally distributed. I also scaled the values of the train and test set using the values from the test set. My train-test split is 80-20.

I understand that it is a good practice to scaled and impute data using only the train set. As this helps avoid over-fit and data leak.

When it comes to Kfold cross validation, the train and test set change.

Question;

Is there a way to ensure that i can re-impute and re-scale the train and test set based on the train set of each fold ?

Any help is appreciated, thank you !

Train-test split using a random seed. Same random seed is used in the K-Fold cross validation.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 3)
```

NA value imputation;

```
from feature_engine import missing_data_imputers as mdi
imputer = mdi.MeanMedianImputer(imputation_method = 'median')
imputer.fit(X_train)
X_train = imputer.transform(X_train)
```

Variable transformation;

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_trans = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_trans = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Below is the SVM;

```
def svm1(gam, C):
clf1 = svm.SVC(gamma=gam, C=C)    
clf1.fit(X_train_trans, y_train)
print('The Trainset Score is {}.'.format(clf1.score(X_train_trans , y_train)))
print('The Testset Score is {}.'.format(clf1.score(X_test_trans , y_test)))
print('')

y_pred1 = clf1.predict(X_test_trans)
print('The confusin matrix is; \n{}'.format(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test , y_pred1)))

interactive(svm1, gam = G1, C = cc1)
```

I then merge the train and test set, to get back a transformed dataset;

```
frames3 = [X_test_trans, X_train_trans ]
X_Final = pd.concat(frames3)
```

Now i fit the X_Final, which is concated train and test set, to get K-fold cross validated score.

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits = 10, random_state = 3)
model = svm.SVC(gamma=0.23, C=3.20)
results = cross_val_score(model, PCA_X_Final,y_Final, cv = kfold)
print(results)
print('Accuracy = {}%, Standard Deviation = {}%'.format(round(results.mean(), 4), round(results.std(), 2)))
```

I would like to know how i can re-scale and re-impute each fold, so that the variables are re-scaled, and NA values re-imputed in each fold using the train set to avoid overfit / dataleak

Comment: add your code please

Comment: I have edited and added the code sir

Comment: Why do you want to rescale and re-impute each fold? The basic idea of K-Fold is to expose the model to limited dataset at a time. Once you have done scaling and imputing as you say it, you don't need to do it again for the partitions. The model should learn the dataset as is from the original imputations and not from the newly computed. If you do so, you're changing the distribution in each partition which doesn't make sense as all of the train data comes from one distribution, the original one.

Comment: if the kfold validator splits the data into n-folds, and uses each fold as test set once, don't the dependent variables need to scaled based on the train test of that particular fold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To impute and scale the data with the parameters derived from each fold in the CV, you first need to establish the engineering steps in a pipeline, and then do CV over the entire pipeline. For example something like this:

set up engineering pipeline:

```
my_pipe = Pipeline([
    # missing data imputation
    ('imputer_num',
     mdi.MeanMedianImputer(imputation_method='mean', variables=['varA', 'varB'])),

    # scaler
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 

    # Gradient Boosted machine (or your SVM instead)
    ('gbm', GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0))
])
```

then the CV:

```
param_grid = {    
    # try different gradient boosted tree model parameters
    'gbm__max_depth': [None, 1, 3],
}


# now we set up the grid search with cross-validation
grid_search = GridSearchCV(my_pipe, param_grid,
                           cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc')
```

More details in [this notebook](https://github.com/solegalli/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning/blob/master/Section-13-Putting-it-altogether/13.03-Assembling-pipeline-with-crossvalidation.ipynb).